# Can you tell whether headphones/headset are plugged in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, headphones

Is it possible to tell whether the headphones are plugged in on a windows phone 8 device?
I want to use the Text to Speech API but I don't want to read messages over the speaker

Comment: i dont see why someone would downvote this question. it's a very valid one.

Comment: I wondered why it got downvoted too, sure it's a short question but it's to the point and I couldn't/can't find a definitive answer

Comment: I'm about to start doing WP8 Development David..so while I'm not able to answer the question, I hope someone does soon. Good luck.

Comment: I was hoping to make a very similar app, did you get anywhere? I found you can't do anything towards this app, you can't run the app in the background and you're not allowed to intercept SMSes, so it seems like it's a no go.

Comment: Additionally my Lumia 1020 has an FM radio, the FM radio app uses the headphones as an areal and gives a warning when they are unplugged, so I guess it must be able to tell when they are unplugged.

Comment: I've created a suggestion for this: http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4861212-read-speak-sms-when-headphones-plugged-in-

Comment: My Lumia 1020 now gives me the option to read text messages when my headphones are plugged in under Settings -> Speech.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, yes you can on WP8.  It's not an obvious API, but these guys figured out how to do it as long as the phone is running anything above GDR1.

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_detect_the_audio_path_(headset_connection)_on_Windows_Phone

Comment: Awesome, will read the article and try it out and then I'll change the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Can we do this in Background task (ie, Windows Runtime component). I have tried but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

See these google results:

1. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpmusic/volume-change-and-headphone-detection-in-wp8/c9ddac53-b55b-4aaf-85ef-e208d69c1c0a
2. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/wpdevelop/thread/7a0766ad-a2c0-4e98-88f8-80e88fa1a175

Comment: Nothing massively conclusive but it's all pointing towards a no. It's very annoying since clearly the SMS/speech function uses this somehow

Comment: if it isn't possible, then how does the Beats audio feature gets enabled on my HTC 8x when headphones are plugged in? there's got to be a way

Comment: My guess is that it's a HTX 8x specific thing

Comment: Also, as I say in my comment above, the FM radio on my Lumia 1020 knows whether the headphones are plugged in.